# react i18n - Functions are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use `i18n` for localization in my class component.

this is what I have:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import i18n from '../i18n';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

var termFlag = require("../json/terms_flag.json")
var termHelper = require("../json/terms_helper.json")

class Terms extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            terms:null,
            termsIsLoaded:false
        }
    }
render(){
    const { t } = this.props;
return(
    <div>
    <h1>{t('terms)}</h1>
    {this.state.termsIsLoaded &&
        <pre>{this.state.terms.en}</pre>
    }
    <button onClick={()=>{this.props.parentcallback("Form")}}>click</button>
    </div>
)}
}

export default withTranslation(Terms) ///<-- this cost the problem
```

I got an error:

> Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you
> return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you
> meant to call this function rather than return it.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have not terminated your string :

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import i18n from '../i18n';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

var termFlag = require("../json/terms_flag.json")
var termHelper = require("../json/terms_helper.json")

class Terms extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            terms:null,
            termsIsLoaded:false
        }
    }
render(){
    const { t } = this.props;
return(
    <div>
    <h1>{t('Terms')}</h1>
    {this.state.termsIsLoaded &&
        <pre>{this.state.terms.en}</pre>
    }
    <button onClick={()=>{this.props.parentcallback("Form")}}>click</button>
    </div>
)}
}

export default withTranslation(Terms) ///<-- this cost the problem
```

This should work.